# Windows Form wont close properly

Tags: c#, winforms, refactoring, add-in

I am developing an add-in for outlook 2010.
Basically, I have a button on my ribbon that takes the selected email, and saves it to a text file.  If the email contains a certain subject then the save is done automatically to a hard coded file path.  If not, a windows form is opened asking the user to enter a filepath.

When the user has selected a path, and clicked 'OK' the save takes place and then the form closes... but then it re-opens... it seems to be creating a new instance of it or something... if I click 'Cancel' or 'X' it closes, but I can't see why it's not closing properly the first time.

Below is my code

```
//This is myRibbon.cs
private void btn_SaveFile_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e) 
{
   //other code
   if (subject = "xyz") 
   {
      //other code
      textFile.Save();
   }
   else
   {
      MyPopup popup = new MyPopup();
      popup.ShowDialog();
   }
}

//This is MyPopup.cs
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
   var filePath = txtFilePath.Text;
   if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(filePath)) 
   { 
       SaveEmailToText(filePath); 
      this.Close(); 
   }
   else 
   { //show message box with error }
   this.Close(); 
}

private static void SaveEmailToText(string filePath) 
{
    //other code
    textFile.Save();
}
```

I have simplified this quite a bit so its easier to read.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you need to close or dispose of the form by checking the DialogModalResult..is what appears to be missing can you show how the MyPopup is being declared ..? it's not on the forms Initialize is it..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Consider to use `OpenFileDialog` instead of your popup form
- Use your popup (or file dialog) only for getting file name
- Keep email saving code in one place (otherwise you will have duplicated code)
- Verify `DialogResult` of dialog form, before processing further
- Forms are disposable - `using` statement will dispose them automatically
- Do not close dialog form - set it's `DialogResult` property instead

Here is refactored code:

```
private void btn_SaveFile_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e) 
{
   string filePath = defaultPath;

   if (subject != "xyz") 
   {
      using(MyPopup popup = new MyPopup())
      {
         // user can close popup - handle this case
         if (popup.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
             return;
         filePath = popup.FilePath;
      }
   }       

   SaveEmailToText(filePath);
}

private void SaveEmailToText(string filePath) 
{
   //other code
   textFile.Save();
}
```

And your popup, which should be replaced with `OpenFileDialog`:

```
private void btnOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(FilePath))
    { 
        //show message box with error
        DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;
        return;
    }

    // you can assign default dialog result to btnOK in designer
    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
}

public string FilePath
{
    get { return txtFilePath.Text; }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your help, I will give that a try and see how I get on.